# How to use RestTemplate for a POST request for a complex body in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm working with RestTemplate in a Spring Boot project and I try to call a POST. And I'm using this code:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("email", "abc@email.com");
map.add("id", "1234567");

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<Employ> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
        "url", request , Employ.class );
```

Now I want to use RestTemplate to consume a POST request but for a complex object. So the body should look like this:

```
{
"SomeThing":{
  "Expr":"cdjhcdjh" 
},
"SomeInfo":{
 "Progr":"EVZpoiuyt",
 "Other": "{code: \"abcd\", password:\"12345\"}"
 }
}
```

How can I create the Map for this body? Any feedback will be apreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create Java objects (POJO) representing the data you would like to send via `RestTemplate`.

For example:

```
public class ObjectToPost {
  private SomeThing someThing;
  private SomeInfo someInfo;

 // getters & setters
}

public class SomeThing {
 private String expr;
     
 // getters & setters
}

public class SomeInfo {
  private String progr;
  private String other;
     
  // getters & setters
}
```

Then you could use this object in your RestTemplate.

```
ObjectToPost obj = new ObjectToPost();
obj.setSomeThing(...)
obj.setSomeInfo(...)
restTemplate.postForEntity("url", obj , Employ.class);
```

You could also use a Map but it will make it quite complex. If you really would like to achieve it with a Map you should create a `<String,Object>` map like:

```
  MultiValueMap<String, Object> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
  MultiValueMap<String, MultiValueMap<String, Object>> somethingMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
  something.put("SomeThing", Map.of("Expr","cdjhcdjh");
  map.put(somethingMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use some other Http client and not `RestTemplate`. So if you have to use `RestTemplate` this answer is not relevant. I wrote my own Http client, and while it might be limited in what it can do its major advantage is simplicity. Your code may look like:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
String response = client.sendHttpRequest("www.myurl.com", HttpClient.HttpMethod.POST, "{\"yourJson\":\"here\"");
```

Here is Javadoc for [HttpClient](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html) class. The library can be obtained as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and javadoc)